# Moving Bitcoin from Bitcoin Core to another Bitcoin Core or Bitcoin Diamond

Tags: bitcoin-core

Before I even begin I'm going to admit that I know it was my fault in the end.

I was part of a community for crypto on a chatting server. I've been a part of it for more than a year. I got to know some people and asked one of the people I knew about getting some help for the following:

I've had a Bitcoin Core Wallet on my desktop from 2016 that I've held my Bitcoin in this whole time. I knew there were waves of up and down to come but I didn't want to sell. Part of being a hodler and thought I had helped the Bitcoin price by just keeping it and not doing anything with it.

Recently I had asked if anyone had experience with forks from a Bitcoin Core Wallet in said chatting community. One of the guys I know said he did and was willing to help. We got on TeamViewer and set everything up for forking. I had my Bitcoin Core Wallet on my desktop that was a bit outdated and a new laptop that I said would be better to put new wallets on for processing wallet nodes faster. We had done the BTG Core Wallet the other day and was going to do the Bitcoin Diamond one. He said that it would have to be a bit different from the Bitcoin Cash and Bitcoin Gold ones we did.

We got on Team Viewer again and I started downloading the Bitcoin Diamond Core Wallet on my laptop. He said it wasn't going to work on the laptop so we needed to connect on my Desktop that has the original Bitcoin Core Wallet. I said I wasn't comfortable with moving any Bitcoins out of the wallet itself and that I wouldn't let him have any control over the session. He said it was fine and would just type on the chat system of what he needed me to do (as usual). He asked that I had the wallet open so he can just look and tell me what to do. After he connected he said he would brb so I waited. After a few minutes, and almost instantly, before I could do anything he had sent a request from my BTC Core Wallet to transfer to an unknown address and clicked the shut down on my computer.

I was still on the laptop and he was in the chat so I just asked why and wanted to know what he did. He said that he "sent it to the BCD addy". I didn't know what he meant so I asked. He said "you need to send it onto the bcdblockchain im pretty sure" and that I should have the Bitcoin Diamond on the Bitcoin Diamond Core Wallet on my laptop. The BTD wallet is not synced and said we had to wait for it to finish (still not finished). After that he appeared offline and hasn't spoken to me from that point (late last night).

My question is this:
potential situation #1: **If** he did send said BTC to the BTD wallet, what should I do?

potential situation #2: **If** he sent to the Bitcoin Core wallet on said laptop instead what should I do? That one is also syncing as I put it on in case I had to move wallets, but it looks like he might have put the .dat file on it from desktop wallet (not sure).

Potential situation #3: **If** he moved it out of said wallet I don't control is there anything I can do? I know I would have to report a theft, but anything else?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> **he moved it out of said wallet I don't control**

Yes, your helper stole all your money.

> **is there anything I can do?**

No, report the theft to the police.

Your money is gone forever though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question but I will try to help..
First you should never give access to your pc except your self, if he transfer the coins to their own address you can't access them with simple words he stole your coins, to check if you still own the coins check your addresses from core wallet in a fork block explorer